# How to append dynamically created div to container

Tags: jquery, dom

I need to display a message from the server (log out) in a dynamic div. I can get it to work if I have the div element coded into the page as such:

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

with the css #message{display:none;} using this js

```
$('#LogOut').on('click', function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PHP/LogOut.php",
        success: function(data) {
        $('#message').fadeIn('fast').html('<p><span>Somesite.com</span>' + data + '<a id="close" href="">X</a></p>');
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

I cannot get this to work with .append, I don't want to have to hard code the  on each page. Is there a good way to create this dynamically and append to div#main on each and every page when you click log out? I have no issues other than this, PHP is fine, log out works fine etc...
thank you.

Comment: Did you search for jQuery `append` ? http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Also consider using `templates` and `includes`, rather than hardcoding.

Comment: @m.spyratos yes I did, and stated that in the last paragraph of my question. I use templates and includes, which in the end still output 'hardcoded' html. I wanted to do this all dynamically.

Comment: Hahah! I missed that! Strange. My apologies...

Comment: no worries, I appreciate you taking the time to even look at the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
$('<div id="message"></div>').appendTo(document.body).html('<p><span>Somesite.com</span>' + data + '<a id="close" href="">X</a></p>').fadeIn('fast');
```

The thing with `append` is that it doesn't return the appended element, it keeps returning the parent element.

```
$(document.body).append($('<div></div>')) //returns $(document.body);
```

Comment: thank you very much. I was not aware of appendTo, only append. I appreciate the help man, very cool - exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Of couse, had to wait 5 min.